# Highcharts custom legend SVG symbol does not fade when you click to turn off series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When using a custom legend symbol, turning off the series by clicking on the legend fades the legend text but does not fade the custom symbol.

This creates inconstancy compared to using inbuilt legend symbols that do fade.

Example here - http://jsfiddle.net/hnc27nf2/

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
          series: [{
            data: [],
            id: 'main',
            marker: {
              symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
            }
          }, {
            linkedTo: 'main',
            data: [1, 3, -2, -4]
          }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: unselected legend items doesn't "fade" they just change color [Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemHiddenStyle). So for the image symbol you will have to create a function on the legend click event.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, following @Core972 comment:

We can fade out the element but changing the opacity of the element: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lzgexfvo/

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function() {
        if (this.legendSymbol) {
          if (this.visible) {
            this.legendSymbol.css({
              opacity: 0.4,
              filter: 'alpha(opacity=40)'
            });
          } else {
            this.legendSymbol.css({
              opacity: 1,
              filter: 'alpha(opacity=100)'
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```